# Beginner Python programmer, need help in making code shorter

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Using third party library named "nsetools" for fetching stock data**

```
from nsetools import Nse
nse = Nse()

stocks = {
    "ADANIPORTS" : 284.95,
    "HINDALCO"   : 152.30,
    "ONGC"       : 279.70,
    "SBIN"       : 259.70
}

qty = {
    "ADANIPORTS" : 20,
    "HINDALCO"   : 20,
    "ONGC"       : 20,
    "SBIN"       : 20
}
```

**I want to make the code starting from here short**

```
### Adaniports
stock1      = nse.get_quote('adaniports')
stock1Close = stock1['closePrice']

### Hindalco
stock2      = nse.get_quote('hindalco')
stock2Close = stock2['closePrice']

### ONGC
stock3      = nse.get_quote('ongc')
stock3Close = stock3['closePrice']

### SBIN
stock4      = nse.get_quote('sbin')
stock4Close = stock4['closePrice']

current_value = (stock1Close * qty['ADANIPORTS']) + (stock2Close * qty['HINDALCO']) + (stock3Close * qty['ONGC']) + (stock4Close * qty['SBIN'])
```

Is there any way to loop through the dictionary, access the closing prices of each individual stock and then calculate the current value of the investment preferably in one or two lines?

Comment: check http://codereview.stackexchange.com, they'll help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs to code review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and received the answer

```
def get_closing(stock):
    return nse.get_quote(stock)['closePrice']

stock_gen = (get_closing(stock) * qty for stock, qty in stock_qty.items())
current_value = sum(stock_gen)
```

Answer (score -1):

To do this as a one liner you can sum over a list comprehension, `[expression for var in collection]`. Reference section 5.1.3 in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
current_value = sum([nse.get_quote(n.lower())['closePrice'] * qty[n] for n in qty.keys()])
```

Comment: While this may be a valid answer, you are much more likely to help others by explaining what the code does and how it works. Code-only answers tend to receive less positive attention and aren't as useful as other answers.

Comment: @Aurora0001 Thank you for the recommendation.  I added some additional explanation.